# How to change bullets color in OpenOffice Impress?

Tags: openoffice-impress

I had some presentation with black text with black bullets. Then I put text on dark background and made it white. Bullets remain black.

How to make them white too?

Answer (score 5):

**Edit**: For newer versions of OpenOffice and LibreOffice it's sufficient to just select a new font color for the text. The bullet-point will change with the text now.

---

Yeah, that's not really intuitive like it should be.

*First of all i should say i do this with LibreOffice (and not OpenOffice) so i don't know if the following also goes for OpenOffice.*

In "Writer" the bullets take the color of the text. In "Impress" they do **not**.

You need to set the color of the bullets manually. You can do this by selecting all the text (and thus the bullets). Click `Format`, `Bullets and Numbering` and the Tab `Customize`. There you can change the color of the bullets. (Don't leave it on `Automatic`)  (See below if this options is not there)

[image]

Since this option is only available in LibreOffice (and not OpenOffice) there is another method:

> You need to create a new character style (open the Stylist - F11 - right click the Default entry then New) give it a name and in the Font Effects tab, select the color you want. Now you can select your bullet-line and choose the correct Character style (select your new style).

[image]

---

**Edit**: Please note that in the newer versions of OpenOffice and LibreOffice it's sufficient to just select a new font color for the text. The bullet-point will change with the text now.

[image]

Comment: 'Bullets and Numbering' is there in version 4.x of OpenOffice.
This looks like the same info, for reference - http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=15179

Comment: I do this and hit okay but the colors never apply. Opening it back up and it's still Automatic.

Comment: @Coburn I edited the answer a bit. For OpenOffice you need to select the new Character Style you just created. (Did you create a new style??) I also added an edit because in newer versions of OpenOffice and LibreOffice these steps are no longer necessary. The Bullet-points are colored in the same color as the text by default.

Comment: I'm trying to modify the bullets in the master slide of an Impress file. I don't believe there is a character class button in Impress (at least in the master slide view, see http://imgur.com/10NqWXS). However, it seems on the computer I'm currently using it works, but not on the one at home. The one at home has other problems too so I'm going to update the copy when I get back. Realize though, the option you mention at the top _is_ in OpenOffice. The second method is just for writer.

Comment: @Coburn I didn't know you were doing this in OO Impress. It seems the latest version of OO Impress **does** have a color-option for the Bullets (which is missing from OO Writer). http://i.imgur.com/cNI4Jd5.png In OO/LO Writer the bullet becomes the same color as the text after it and in OO/LO Impress it can be set independently. (It's weird they both have a different bullet-dialog)

Comment: @Rik Ends up just being a problem with this one PC. Updating did not help. I doubt there's an easy way to fix now that I know this is a bug. https://vid.me/hyKr